# How internal energy changes when degree of freedom is 1 and T is constant

Tags: thermodynamics

Actually there is a CV thats draining... With liquid and vapor and a vapor quality, we drain it while T is constant,as i know from gibbs phase law, the F must be 1 , so if T is constant ,U and H must be constant too, the problem asks the Q when half of the CV is drained, in energy eq formula i replaced d(MU) with Udm , but the solution says M2U2-M1U1 , i dont undestand why...the solution just keeps the enthalpy constant because T is constant,and i think U must be like that too but we see that it changes,sorry for my bad english, i appreciate your help.
Here is the problem :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZ9T.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The drained water is in liquid form, always. So keeping the temperature constant makes its enthalpy constant. But, since the vapor quality is changed the U in the system changes, too. Constant T means constan U only if no phase change is occuring. Here, there occurs a phase change and this causes a raise for U. Note also that the exiting water does not change phase. It is pure liquid water. So its enthalpy stays same.

Comment: I understood most of your answer, but i dont get what phase change is occuring..there is always vapor and liquid in the tank.

Comment: while draining the water the volume of the vapor in the tanks increases to avoid this phenomenon the liquid water vaporizes. (You can take a look at vapor pressure about this issue.) However, the question is intended to be simple and keeps the temperature constant so you do not deal with vapor pressure.